# Generating square wave in portAudio

Tags: c++, qt, portaudio

I'm trying to generate sound using square wave. Sound is playing but it sound too harsh. 
Here is code of my example:

```
for(int i=0; i<SE_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
{
    abc = 0.1*sin(2 * M_PI * data.soundPitch[freq] * ((double)i/(double)SAMPLE_RATE));
    if(abc >= 0)
        data.sine[i] += 0.05;
    else
        data.sine[i] += -0.05;
}
Pa_Sleep(duration);
for(int i=0; i<SE_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
{
    abc = 0.1*sin(2 * M_PI * data.soundPitch[freq] * ((double)i/(double)SAMPLE_RATE));
    if(abc >= 0)
        data.sine[i] -= 0.05;
    else
        data.sine[i] -= -0.05;
}
```

I'm generating sine wave and then I'm checking the values. If it's grater than 0 - 0.05 is assigned. Otherwise it's -0.05. In my opinion it should work, but as I wrote earlier - it's too harsh. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? Maybe you have better solution?

Comment: I've realised that at higher pitch samples looks like "-1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 1" so I've set sampling rate at 44100 and it's much better now. But at highest frequencies it's still harshy, but not as much as earlier.

Comment: For generating a square wave of frequency F, all you need is to generate a table of (44100/F) samples.  Populate the first half of that table with positive values, then populate the second half of the table with negative values, then play the table's samples over and over again, in an infinite loop.  In particular, for a square wave there is no need to ever call sin().

Comment: If you're hearing distortion during playback, it may be that your audio buffer is underrunning, causing additional/unwanted discontinuities in the audio signal's output values.